# how to find the element which are on screen during scroll jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to find the element which are on screen during scroll jquery.

Currently , I am using stick navbar with scroll.When we scroll down or up automatically the link in the navbar should be enabled.

I tried http://codetheory.in/change-active-state-links-sticky-navigation-scroll/ and able to succeed.

One problem is the link getting enabled when it reached the top of the screen. But I need the link to be enabled when the element is reached the center of the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look to this library: https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen It's very easy to use and achieve what you ask for

Answer (score 1):

Just add a half of the window height to the current position:

```
var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2;
```

And subtract it when you click on a link:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height - $(window).height() / 2
}, 500);
```

Try this snippet (better open it in full-screen):

```js
var sections = $('section')
  , nav = $('nav')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2;
  
  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
    
    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');
      
      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});

nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
  var $el = $(this)
    , id = $el.attr('href');
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height - $(window).height() / 2
  }, 500);
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  background: #1ABC9C;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #34495E;
}
a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
}

/* Headings */

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #34495E;
}

/* Sections */

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #bdc3c7;
}
.sections section:first-child {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
section.active {}

footer {
  height: 500px;
  background: #34495e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1" class="active">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="sections">
  <section id="1"><h1>First</h1></section>
  <section id="2"><h1>Second</h1></section>
  <section id="3"><h1>Third</h1></section>
  <section id="4"><h1>Fourth</h1></section>
  <section id="5"><h1>Fifth</h1></section>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thanks @kirill, It's not working properly.But  in Ipad, when I click third ,scrolling is moving to third but in sticky menu it is pointing same.any inputs

Comment: @sree You're right, didn't notice it. You should also subtract a half of the window height when you click on a link. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following code:

```js
var sections = $('section')
  , nav = $('nav')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight()
  , win_height = $(window).height();
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  sections.each(function() {
    
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
 
    if (bottom >= (win_height / 2 + cur_pos) ) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');
      
      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
      return false;
    }
  });
});

nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
  var $el = $(this)
    , id = $el.attr('href');
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height
  }, 500);
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  background: #1ABC9C;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #34495E;
}
a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
}

/* Headings */

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #34495E;
}

/* Sections */

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #bdc3c7;
}
.sections section:first-child {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
section.active {}

footer {
  height: 500px;
  background: #34495e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="sections">
  <section id="1"><h1>First</h1></section>
  <section id="2"><h1>Second</h1></section>
  <section id="3"><h1>Third</h1></section>
  <section id="4"><h1>Fourth</h1></section>
  <section id="5"><h1>Fifth</h1></section>
</div>

<footer></footer>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope, it helps :)

Comment: Thanks @jsamin It's not working properly.But in Ipad, when I click third ,scrolling is moving to third but in sticky menu it is pointing same.any inputs

Comment: Can you please state, how it doesn't work ? And I can't understand the iPad
issue. Can you please rephrase it ?